# A Riddle: To speak to an ancient Siberian brassiere

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> You might find it strange
> To speak to an ancient Siberian brassiere.
> I could fix your car,
> But I'll surely break the laws there.
> News of me has recently been big,
> Though that doesn't make sense at all.
> You couldn't see me wave,
> Because I'm actually very small.

What am I?

Include your reasoning for each clue (each line is a clue.)

#### Hint

> Line 2: The language is dying quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

> Quantum Mechanics

You might find it strange

> Reference to Strange quark, or possibly the seemingly strange behavior of matter at the quantum scale.

To speak to an ancient Siberian brassiere.

> Reference to [bra-ket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) notation used in Quantum Mechanics.  [Ket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleosiberian_languages) is an ancient Siberian language which is dying out.  "Bra" is short for brassiere.

I could fix your car,

> A **mechanic** fixes your car.

But I'll surely break the laws there.

> Physics at the quantum scale seems to break the macro-scale laws of physics

News of me has recently been big,

> Interest in QM continues to rise...

Though that doesn't make sense at all.

> QM has to do with things that are *small*  not *big*

You couldn't see me wave,

> QM has a lot to do with understanding wave functions in objects too small to see.

Because I'm actually very small.

> Again, QM deals with the very small

Comment: Correct! For the 5th clue, I was specifically referencing [this](http://www.research.ibm.com/quantum/), but of course there are plenty of other relevant articles.

Answer (score 4):

> You might find it strange
>   To speak to an ancient Siberian brassiere.

Okay, let's say that this is about

> getting information from an decaying (old) radioactive isotope (icy top)

---

> I could fix your car,
>   But I'll surely break the laws there.

And we'll guess that this means it's

> connected with something a car needs, like oil or gas, but also legally questionable behaviors or incidents.

---

> News of me has recently been big,
>   Though that doesn't make sense at all.

And this is likely intimating that

> current articles exist about this isotope (small particle)

---

> You couldn't see me wave,
>   Because I'm actually very small.

Which means this is just

> more hints at this being a radioactive particle, possibly emitting waves.

---

Thus, my guess is we're referring to

> [Radioactive isotopes reveal age of oil and gas wastewater spills](http://phys.org/news/2016-05-radioactive-isotopes-reveal-age-oil.html)

Comment: Nope. Also, each line is a separate hint (clarification added to question.) This riddle is probably the most difficult one I've posted yet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> **Oil**(Crude Oil)/ **Natural gas**?

You might find it strange
To speak to an ancient Siberian brassiere.

> Crude oils/ Natural gas are fossil fuels. [Fossil fuels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_fuel) takes thousands of years to form hence the ancient. Siberia brassiere might refer to oil reserve in Siberia.

I could fix your car,
But I'll surely break the laws there.

> Oil/ gas is necessary to fix/ refuel your car, but refueling you car with Siberian oil/ gas might be illegal due to sanctions imposed by US on it after the Ukraine crisis. [Example](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-russia-sanctions-idUSKCN0QC1UJ20150807)

News of me has recently been big,
Though that doesn't make sense at all.

> Crude oil/ natural gas has recently been in News due to huge fall/ fluctuation in its global price. It doesn't make sense because this is a primary source of fuel for all over the world and should be in large demand at all times.

You couldn't see me wave,
Because I'm actually very small.

> Wave maybe related to huge production wave. We cannot see production wave for oil and gas because it is a natural resource and is very scarce.

Comment: Nope. As I already said, there are 8 separate clues, one for each line.

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> A hadron?

You might find it strange

> hadrons are made up of strange quarks

To speak to an ancient Siberian brassiere.

> not sure about this, but protons and neutrons are examples of hadrons, and they make up molecules on Earth, including those in brassieres.

I could fix your car,

> a car requires protons and neutrons to function

But I'll surely break the laws there.

> cars and hadrons obey different laws of physics at different scales

News of me has recently been big,

> Large Hadron Collider

Though that doesn't make sense at all.

> subatomic physics is foreign to most people

You couldn't see me wave,

> particle-wave duality?

Because I'm actually very small.

> subatomic particle

Comment: Not what I was thinking of. You're in the right general direction, though. The 2nd clue is the hardest.